# Python OpenCV calibrateCamera: objectPoints should contain vector of vectors of points of type Point3f

Tags: python, opencv, camera-calibration

I want to calculate the camera calibration parameters from the picture coordinates and object coordinates of some coded markers.

```
ret, mtx, dist, rvecs, tvecs = cv2.calibrateCamera(points, centers, gray.shape[::-1], None, None)
```

But I get the following error:

```
objectPoints should contain vector of vectors of points of type Point3f in function 'cv::collectCalibrationData'
```

This confuses me because the object points are implemented like this:

```
points=np.float32([[7.8, 4.9, 0], [5.2, 4.9, 0], [7.8, 7.35, 0], [5.2, 7.35, 0], [2.6, 7.35, 0],[10.4, 0, 0],...])
```

and they seem to be mx3-matrix according to a console print and the dimensions from np.shape

```
[[ 7.8   4.9   0.  ]
 [ 5.2   4.9   0.  ]
 [ 7.8   7.35  0.  ]
 [ 5.2   7.35  0.  ]
 [ 2.6   7.35  0.  ]
 [10.4   0.    0.  ]
...]

(20, 3)
```

My image points are calculated from some Aruco-markers and Look like this:

```
[[2639.   1826.5 ]
 [2265.5  1820.5 ]
 [2638.75 1480.  ]
 [2269.   1475.25]
 [1898.   1470.5 ]
 [3024.   2551.25]
...]
(20, 2)
```

I know that coplanar objectpoints are not really suitable for this task. Ive just started to create some dummy data to figure out the syntax of everything :) Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well the answer is quite simple:

```
objpoints=[]
objpoints.append(points)
```

then call cv2.calibrateCamera with objpoints instead of points

Well, there went my sanity :)